# Mustache.js and YQL jSON

Tags: javascript, json, yql, mustache

I am not really sure how to get data out of this nested object with Mustache.js.  I am using the YQL multi query that brings back my data objects nested https://gist.github.com/866247.  My problem comes when I am trying to access the nested objects

The data comes back like this where 0 and 1 are part of an array with objects in them. Here is a picture of the tree http://cl.ly/1e1b3O3U233e2I0d3g2f.

```
   query
       results
          results
               0
               1
```

I have tried the template below and I don't get anything back.  I believe the problem is that that second "results key" comes back with the array and mustache doesn't know what to do.

```
   "{{#query}}
                {{#results}}
                    {{#results}}
                        {{#photo}}
                            {{farm}}
                        {{#photo}}
                    {{/results}}
                {{/results}}
            {{/query}}"
```

If this makes sense to anyone, how do I access the nested objects in the array if there is no key to them?

Comment: Any luck with flattening or traversing with a Moustache helper yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should flatten your data into a simpler format to write a template that makes sense, but you can get pretty close to what you want with it as-is.

The one insurmountable issue I saw was that 'results' is inside 'results' resulting in a tag closure mismatch. Doing something like this solves that problem:

```
 data.query.flattened = data.query.results.results;
```

A functional sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RuVK2/).

You can find some more mustache tricks in [this article](http://blog.couchone.com/post/622014913/mustache-js).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the types of issues with Moustache that Handlebars attempts to address - traversing through objects in the template:

http://handlebars.strobeapp.com/#paths

Where you access it directly as if it's a directory structure. I know this isn't an answer to your question, per-se, but aside from flattening the data it's an alternative solution.

Comment: Yea I looked at handlebars shortly after running into this.  Thanks for the heads up.